# Use Pictures For Labels

Tags: views, entities

Hello ive been trying to work out how to do this for years and ive a feeling its one of them eureka moments when i go 'oh aye thats how you do it'. I think thats why i have never been able to find anything on it.

Using Views 3 my lists look like this when using total views and total comments-

[image]

and i would like to get rid of the label for a wee pic like this-
[image]

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS background image concept to show images instead of Views & Comments text.

It should be very simple & straightforward ! You just need to identify the unique id or class in the html to apply css to that. Below article should be a good starting point for you !

http://stopdesign.com/archive/2003/03/07/replace-text.html

Comment: thanks for the reply Anil. I am on my mobile so typing is a prob. let me try... i will have to wait till i get home. Again thanks.  I will mark this as fixed as youve pointed me on the road i was looking for thanks.